# Why does the value of '?' change depending on my current directory?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have this strange folder on my computer called template/ (I believe it was created when I was doing some low level programming on the raspberry pi). The strange thing is if I am in the folder and I run the command

```
$echo -n ? | hexdump
```

it displays

```
0000000 000d                                   
0000001
```

However, if I am in any other folder the command looks like this

```
$echo -n ? | hexdump
0000000 003f                                   
0000001
```

Why does the value of '?' change in that folder and only that folder.

I should note that the reason I found this was that there was a file named '?' in the template/ folder that was causing problems in some php I was writing. I attempted to recreate it somewhere else but found I was unable to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Why does the value of '?' change in that folder and only that folder.`

`?` is a special character in shell globbing.

`?` matches any character and `echo ?` will match and list **any filename in current directory with exactly 1 character length.**

**PS:** If a directory doesn't have any 1 character filename then **it will echo literal `?`**

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense thank you. It confused me because it still displayed a '?', but the value of that filename is definitely 13.

Comment: Yes as I wrote `?` it will match exactly 1 char filename. If 1 char file doesn't exist in current directory then it prints literal `?`

Answer (score 1):

The expression `echo ?` is processed by [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) first. It replaces `?` with any single character file names if such exists. If there is no such file it remains `?`.

Example (there are two files with single character file name):

```
$ ls ?
b  c
$ echo ?
b c
```

Or (no single character file)

```
$ ls ?
ls: cannot access ?: No such file or directory
$ echo ?
?
```

So if You just want to present a `?` character you need to escape it:

```
$ echo \?
?
$ echo '?'
?
$ echo "?"
?
```

I hope this helps a bit...